# Second order differential equation in function of a real parameter.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this second order ODE:
$$X''+2X'=\lambda X$$
With $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

I suppose I have to define three cases:

- $\lambda<0$
- $\lambda=0$
- $\lambda>0$

Could someone give me a hint to start? Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you can distinguish three cases. Start with $\lambda = 0$. You have $x''+2x'=0$. Then you associate to this differential equation the algebraic equation $\mu^2+2\mu = 0$, which gives $\mu = 0$ or $\mu = -2$. Then the solution is $x(t) = c_1+c_2e^{-2t}$. This is a general method for linear homogeneous ODEs and the possible solutions are classified. You can apply this method again for the other cases (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case) at the voice Second-order case).

Comment: 1) Those are not the three cases we need for this equation, 2) You solved the easiest case and left out the harder ones; this is no way a complete answer

Comment: This is not meant to be a complete answer, as a "hint to start" was asked. Once the asker knows the method, he/she can easily see if those are the three cases to distinguish. That is why I said "you _can_ distinguish three cases" and started with $\lambda = 0$, giving an example of the application of the method.

Answer (score 2):

***Just a hint ***

$$X''+2X'=\lambda X$$
$$X''+2X'-\lambda X=0 $$

First you need the characteristic polynomial. Here it's

$$R^2+2R-\lambda=0$$
The discriminant is 
$$\Delta=b^2-4ac=4+4\lambda= 4(1+\lambda)$$
Thats what you have to discuss. Whether the $\Delta$ is 0, >0,<0...

You have three important cases  $\lambda=-1 ,\quad \lambda >-1$ and finaly $\lambda<-1$....

Answer (score 1):

The solution rests on the roots of the characteristic equation

$$x^2+2x-\lambda=0$$ which are

$$-1\pm\sqrt{1+\lambda}.$$

For $\lambda>-1$ the two roots are real and for $\lambda>0$, one of them is positive, giving an unstable solution.

For $\lambda<-1$, there are two conjugate roots and a damped oscillatory behavior.